# ChiSquare calculation returning all zeros

Tags: python

EDIT: after more trial and error, I figured out that for some reason, python says that 1/52 is 0, can anyone explain me why, so I can avoid this problem in the future?

I've been struggling with a script for a while now, mainly because me or my fellow students simply can't find out what's wrong with it.

Trying to keep things simple, we've got data and a model and we have to rescale some of the datapoints to the model and then do a chi2square minimalization in order to find the best rescaling factor.

I've tried multiple things already. Tried putting everything in 1 loop, when that didn't work, I tried splitting the loops up etc.

The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
#Here I pick the values of the model that correspond to the data
y4 = np.zeros((len(l),1))
for x in range(0,len(l)):
  if l[x] < 2.16:
    for y in range(0,len(lmodel)):
      if lmodel[y] == l[x]:
    y4[x] = y2[y]
      elif lmodel[y] < l[x] < lmodel[y+1]:
    y4[x] = (y2[y] + y2[y+1])/2
  else:
    y4[x] = y1[x]


#Do Chi2 calculation
#First, I make a matrix with all the possible rescaled values
chi2 = np.zeros((200,1))
y3 = np.zeros((len(l),len(chi2)))
for z in range(0,len(chi2)):
  for x in range(0,len(l)):
    if l[x] < 2.16:
      y3[x,z] = y1[x]*10**(0.4*Al[x]*z/100)
    else:
      y3[x,z] = y1[x]

#Here I calculate the chisquare for each individual column and put it in the chi2 array
dummy = np.zeros((len(l),1))
for x in range(0,len(chi2)):
  for t in range(0, len(l)):
    dummy[t] = (1/52)*((y3[t,x] - y4[t])/fle[t])**2
  chi2[x] = np.sum(dummy)
```

The thing is that no matter what I try, for some reason, my dummy array is always all zeros, making every single chi square value 0.

I've tried making 'dummy' a matrix and summing afterwards, I've tried printing individual values for the calculation of the dummy[t]'s, and some of them were 0 (as expected), some weren't, so logically, if the individual values aren't all 0, neither should every value in dummy be.

I just can't find where I go wrong, and why I keep getting arrays of zeros.

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced here: `dummy = np.zeros((len(l),1)`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but that wasn't the problem, otherwise it would have been a simple syntax error. I just figured out what gave the problem, but it confuses me even more.. For some reason, python tells me that 1/52 is 0, so I changed 1/52 to ((52)**(-1)) and now it works...

Comment: What version of python do you use? in python 2.x "1/52" is indeed 0, because the default is integer division, you should make it "1.0/52" to force float operations, in python 3.x this is automatic

Comment: I use 2.7, since it's most commonly used in my field. I didn't know about that though, it's a weird feature, and especially frustrating since I spent hours writing and rewriting my loops because I couldn't figure out what I did wrong. My first attempt (which was way more elegant than what I wrote above) was probably also correct then.

At least I found out the issue...

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird quirk of python, if you don't want to rewrite your code, you can put `from __future__ import division` in the top of your file and it would behave like python 3.x

Comment: @gormar alternatively to writing 1.0 or `from future import division` you could also type `1.0/float( anyVariableName )`. This will cast `anyVariableName` to a floating point and so the division will work as you were expecting.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2 (which most people are still using), `1 / 52` is an integer division, so returns 0.  You can fix it by explicitly using floating point numbers, e.g. `1.0 / 52`.

In Python 3, this is no longer true--dividing two integers can return a float.